# Parsing wikipedia xml dump in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

recently I wanted to work on wikipedia data. In that case I downloaded its en-lang XML dump.
It was over 44GB. I thought I would parse it with XmlSlurper that, according to documentation, is good enough for parsing large XML files. Unfortunately I got some "out of memory exception". Is any way (using existing libs) in Groovy to parse that "monster-file"?

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSlurper` does use a SAX parser under the covers, but it loads the data into an internal model and is therefore not ideal for parsing really large files.

I believe you'll need to use a [native SAX parser](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+with+Groovy+and+SAX), or something else (xslt?) depending on your use-case

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a tool that can process the XML in a streaming fashion rather than loading the whole thing into a tree model in memory up-front.  You could use SAX (where you write your code as event handler methods which the parser then calls as it works its way through the document) or StAX (where you "pull" events from the parser rather than having the parser "push" them at you), but another alternative would be to use a model like [XOM](http://www.xom.nu) which can operate in a kind of "semi-streaming" mode, giving you the tree model for just one `<page>` of the dump at a time:

```groovy
import nu.xom.*

class PageHandler extends NodeFactory {
  private Nodes EMPTY = new Nodes()

  Closure handler

  public Nodes finishMakingElement(Element e) {
    if(e.localName == 'page') {
      handler.call(e)
      return EMPTY
    } else {
      return super.finishMakingElement(e)
    }
  }
}

// call it as
new Builder(new PageHandler(handler:{ page ->
  def latestRevText =
       page.getFirstChildElement('revision').getFirstChildElement('text').value
  // ...
})).build(fileOrInputStreamOrReader)
```

You can do a similar trick with some other libraries, e.g. [Dom4J](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+with+Groovy+and+DOM4J).